# Logging to the console randomly selected array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, logging, random

**I am new to coding, started about a week ago by using resources such as Mark Myers' book titled "A Smarter Way to Learn Javascript" and online tutorials. I wanted to experiment with something but so far did not succeed.**

In a nutshell, I want to start with three arrays. Two of which will have three values each, and the third initially an empty array. I want each value of the first array to be concatenated with each value of the second array and the result added to the third - initially empty - array. Since the first and second arrays each contain three values, there will be nine combinations altogether, resulting in nine values in the third array.

What I want to achieve is to display *one* of the possible three combinations *for each value of the first array*. I want this to happen in a random fashion, using the statements the aforementioned book already covered, ones I am already aware of, without wandering into uncharted territories.

My approach was to create three random numbers, each of which represents a value (index, to be more exact) in the third array that will house the combinations (concatenations) of the first and second arrays. Thus, I wanted the first random number to be either 0, 1 or 2 to "choose" a possible combination for the first value of the first array, the second random number to be either 3, 4 or 5 to choose a possible combination for the second value of the first array, and finally, a third random number, either 6, 7 or 8 to point to a combination for the third value of the first array.

The goal was to log the randomly selected combinations (concatenations) - **one for each value of the first array** - in the console. In other words, I am **expecting to see three concatenations** in the log. However, the console only returns one concatenation.

Can someone please shed some light what exactly is missing or wrong? I believe the problem in my code lies in the last line but so far cannot figure out what exactly is the issue. I am also unsure why Visual Studio Code (I am using the "Prettier" extension) modifies my formatting of the last line from

```
console.log(strNum[num1, num2, num3]);
```

to

```
console.log(strNum[(num1, num2, num3)]);
```

upon saving the file but maybe this has nothing to do with my issue.

My code is the following:

```
// Declaring variables for the operation
var str = ["a ", "b ", "c "]; // Array str to hold strings a, b and c
var num = ["1", "2", "3"]; // Array num to hold numbers 1, 2 and 3
var strNum = []; // Array strNum to hold all possible combinations of array str and array num
var k = 0; //Counter for array strNum

// Combining the contents of array str and array num and adding the combinations to array strNum
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
    strNum[k] = str[i] + num[j];
    k++;
  }
}

// The first random number between with the possible values 0, 1 or 2, to determine the first pair
var bigDecimal1 = Math.random();
var improvedDecimal1 = bigDecimal1 * 3;
var RandomNum1 = Math.floor(improvedDecimal1);

// The second random number between with the possible values 3, 4 or 5, to determine the second pair
var bigDecimal2 = Math.random();
var improvedDecimal2 = bigDecimal2 * 3 + 3;
var randomNum2 = Math.floor(improvedDecimal2);

// The third - and last - random number between with the possible values 6, 7 or 8, to determine the third pair
var bigDecimal3 = Math.random();
var improvedDecimal3 = bigDecimal3 * 3 + 6;
var randomNum3 = Math.floor(improvedDecimal3);

console.log(strNum[(num1, num2, num3)]);
```

Comment: Not 100% clear, but is this what you want? `console.log([strNum[RandomNum1], strNum[randomNum2], strNum[randomNum3]]);`

Comment: Oh yeah! That is exactly what I wanted! I thought I could just simply "list" the three random numbers one after the other.

I also noticed I incorrectly named my random numbers (their names are different from the declared variable names, in fact, I forgot to rename them when I renamed the variables earlier) in the last line of my code.

Your resolution works exactly the way I imagined. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier tries to correct your code. You can't have `console.log(strNum[num1, num2, num3])`, as you can only pick one element from an array at a time. `strNum[num1]` should work fine, as you pass a number (this is the index of the element).

When you provide more than one variable, Prettier tries to group what's inside the square brackets. That's why it adds the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) (extra parentheses).

You can pick one element at a time like this:

```js
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min);
}

let first = random(0, 2);
let second = random(3, 5);
let third = random(6, 8);

// Declaring variables for the operation
let str = ["a ", "b ", "c "];
let num = ["1", "2", "3"];
let strNum = [];
let k = 0;

// Combining the contents of array str and array num and adding the combinations to array strNum
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
    strNum[k] = str[i] + num[j];
    k++;
  }
}

console.log(strNum[first], strNum[second], strNum[third]);
// Or you can log a new array
console.log([strNum[first], strNum[second], strNum[third]]);
```

I also created a `random()` function so you don't have to repeat yourself. And please, don't make global variables. Declare the `i` and `j` inside your `for` loops.

Comment: Köszi szépen, Zsolti!
Thank you! I am not yet familiar with functions, they come in the next chapters of my book. I also noticed I incorrectly named my random numbers in the last line of my code. Initially, my random number variables were called num1, num2 and num3, but I renamed them for more clarity to randomNum1, randomNum2 and randomNum3, but I forgot to rename them in the last line. Rookie mistake.

Appreciate your help,
Üdv, Zsolt

Comment: Oh, what a surprise, another Zsolt. That's great :) Keep reading that book and don't give up after reading the upcoming chapters. Also, if you think it was helpful, you should consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer. Cheers ;)

Comment: Thank you, Zsolti! I certainly clicked the "This answer was useful" (upvote) arrow but it the following is displayed: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."